# Create a general javascript or jquery to make a div or tag set focus on first input inside of it when the div or tag clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm developing a form to enter data, which is using table to align its layout. I have two columns, which the first column was for the input title, and the second column was mostly for the input tags. I have made the inputs inside the second column to be transparent and no borders, so it will looks like we really write inside the table itself. With only one problem: I give the table cell padding to make it feel spacious and less crumply. So the input are sitting a the center of each table's cell on the second column, with a white padding space surrounds it. If I need to change the content of the input, I need to exactly click on the input, which feels weird as I set the td's cursor CSS to be cursor:text. I want that if the user click on the td (or a div, for general), the javascript or jquery will automatically select only the first **text** input or **textarea**, **inside** the td?

example code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><textarea name="address" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Day of Birth</td>
        <td class="noautoselect">
            <input type="text" name="day">
            <input type="text" name="month">
            <input type="text" name="year">
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the first and second example, I want that the user can click on the second td and have the input or textarea set on focus instead.

In the third example, I don't want the user to set focus or select the first option because they accidentally clicked on td area. They're not text input, so they don't need to be counted on autofocus selection. And there's no another input text at that td, so no input need to gain any focus.

In the fourth example, I don't want the user to always set focus or select the first input (day) if the user accidentally click on the whole td area when he wants to click on month input, for example. Therefore, I set a class for the td `noautoselect` to selectively exclude any td or tag for checked for any input inside it.

Thanks.

Comment: To avoid being flamed in the future, you should always post any code you've attempted to solve the problem with and describe in detail how it hasn't worked.

Comment: I'm hoping to have a general solution for this problem, and that requires to be able to work with codes I haven't developed yet. And this code is almost identical to my working code except for field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery snippet will accomplish what you want.

```
$("td").not(".noautoselect").on("click",function(){
    $(this).find("input[type='text'], textarea").focus();
});
```

1. We select all the td elements
2. We remove any of those with a class of noautoselect
3. Bind our click event to the tds

When one of our non '.noautoselect' tds is clicked:

1. Select the td using `$(this)` - this refers to the DOM element in jQuery callbacks
2. Within that element, find all inputs with a type of text, and all textareas.
3. Focus those elements.

This will attempt to focus everything it selected, so if you have more than 1 input or text area in a valid td, it will focus the last one, since that was the final one that a focus event was called on. To avoid this, we can select the first one:

```
$("td").not(".noautoselect").on("click",function(){
    $(this).find("input[type='text'], textarea").first().focus();
});
```

Or decide that if there's more than 1, we really don't want to be auto focusing anyway.

```
$("td").not(".noautoselect").on("click",function(){
    var $inputs = $(this).find("input[type='text'], textarea");
    if ( $inputs.length == 1 ){ $inputs.focus(); }
});
```

Comment: Oh... my God. This is very elegant and it's working! This is like magic! It's like you're translating the requirement from English into code! I'm not understand jQuery, so when I were trying to build this code by myself in Javascript, it were very complex for me and it also not working. So I thought maybe it will be easier in jQuery but I don't understand a thing about it. You also gives me a quick course crash with this little code, and I'm very thankful about this. I hope I can upvote your answer million times! Thanks!